# R - creating a conversion function for morse code

Tags: r, function, if-statement, return

I try to write a function that converts morse signs to letters and reverse.
I load a csv file with column 1 = letters (A,B,C,...) and column 2= codes (..-.  --..  ...-).
Four signs represent one letter.
I have a file of 32 rows with two columns with the equivalents.

Now I want to convert the code into letters (decrypt) or letters into code (encrypt), depending on the mode I choose in the function.

I startet with:

```
MorsFunk <- function(code,Mode){
+   if(Mode=="encodieren"& code==Morsen[1,1]) return(Morsen[1,2])
+   else warning("Dies ist keine korrekte Eingabe!")
+ }
```

I entered code and mode as arguments. Code shall be a string of characters; and mode shall be a binary choice to choose the direction of conversion. I just tried this code:
if Mode was "encodieren" and the entered code in code was the same as a certein element in the data.frame (I would repeat this if request for each 32 element), I expected that return(Morsen[1,2] returns the equivalent code.
I am a newcomer and I would be pleased to give me any idea how to do this? I am doing it as hobby and it is not for academic or proofessional purposes - thank you!

Comment: At the moment I think this is a little bit too high-level to make a good problem: can you get a little bit farther on your one?  (1) As a step toward a [mcve] it would help if you could post a few lines of your CSV file (e.g. in code format), e.g. just the encodings for A, B, C, then show the desired conversion of (say) "ABAC" to ".- -... .- -.-." (according to https://morsecode.world/international/translator.html ). (2) `strsplit()`, `match()`, and a `for` loop will probably get you most of the way there ... (maybe `paste()` with the `collapse` argument too()

Answer (score 1):

This should get you most of the way to your function. First we need reproducible data. I found a .csv file on the web and added a line at the bottom to encode spaces. Here is the data frame in reproducible form produced using `dput()`:

```
morse <- 
structure(list(character = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", 
"H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", 
"U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", ",", "?", ":", "-", "\"", "(", "=", "*", ".", 
";", "/", "'", "_", ")", "+", "@", " "), code = c(".-", "-...", 
"-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", 
".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", 
"..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", "-----", ".----", 
"..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", 
"----.", "__..__", "..__..", "___...", "_...._", "._.._.", "_.__.", 
"_..._", "_.._", "._._._", "_._._.", "_.._.", ".____.", "..__._", 
"_.__._", "._._.", ".__._.", "   ")), row.names = c(NA, 53L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now we need a test text string. Note that we want only uppercase letters and we need to split the string into individual characters.

```
test <- toupper("This is a test.")
(test.spl <- unlist(strsplit(test, "")))
#  [1] "T" "H" "I" "S" " " "I" "S" " " "A" " " "T" "E" "S" "T" "."
```

Now we can encode the string putting a space between each Morse code and three spaces between words:

```
encode <- morse$code[match(test.spl, morse$character)]
paste0(encode, collapse=" ")
# [1] "- .... .. ...     .. ...     .-     - . ... - . _ . _ . _"
```

To go back to the original string:

```
decode <- morse$character[match(encode, morse$code)]
paste0(decode, collapse="")
# [1] "THIS IS A TEST."
```

You should look at the manual pages for each of these functions to see how they work and can be modified to suit your purposes (e.g. `?toupper`).

Comment: Hello, thank you very much. it is a very good result !!! Is there any chance to write an individual function (not predefined one)? Starting like .. morse <- function(code,mode){

Comment: and the mode was a choice between "decrypt" and "encrypt"? But it is just out of interese

Comment: Sure just use your original function and use these code blocks with `if(Mode=="encrypt") { ... }` and `else { ... }`. You will probably need to use `strsplit(x, " ")` for the decoding block. Did you just want to encode/decode single letters or a whole text string?